# Update result of formula in text box

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to update an unbound text box in a form I'm building.

The text box has a default value which is: `=DLookUp("[Metadata]![Username]";"[Metadata]")`.

When the value in the field `username` is changed;
how do I update this change in the text box without closing the whole form and then opening it again?

--

I've tried to to do this by adding a button in the form and then on mouse up event try and either by vba or the macro editor find a solution.

- It would supposedly be possible to create a macro that will close and then open the form again but it's not really what I'm looking for.
- VBA: I found lots of suggestions for `requery` but I couldn't get this to work:
  `Set UserName = Forms![Update test]!Text10
  UserName.Requery`

A general solution that could work with multiple such text boxes is preferable
(but not required, anything that tries to point me in the right direction is welcome).

Comment: How is the data in the [Metadata]![Username] field updated? Is this on a bound form ? And by the way you don't need the [Metadata]! bit in the first part of the dlookup either.

Comment: You need to refresh the form, use Me.Refresh.

Comment: @Minty [Metadata]![Username] is a table updated manually (thus far). So first I opened the form and then changed the data in the Metadata table and tried to get this data updated in the form. Thanks for the heads up about the [metadata]! part.

Comment: @Jeffrey Do you mean in conjuction with Requery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the design view and select the textbox which represents your table value `username`, then go to events and select the `On Change()` event:

```
Private Sub username_Change()

  YourTextbox.Value =DLookUp("[Metadata]![Username]";"[Metadata]")

End Sub
```

Comment: That will only work if the data is changed on the form. I get the impression from the OP That this is not necessarily the case. But I could be misunderstanding.

Comment: This only updates the textbox when I try and do changes to the textbox itself. 

Also while the answer does not solve this in a general way (because the solution is specific to that textbox) it is definitely pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You can always use other events which might help you for your specific case